# Linear Matrix differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $A,B$ be non-singular matrices of dimension $n\times n$.  Is there a way to solve the differential equation
$$
f(x)Bx=A\nabla_x f(x)?
$$
I've looked in many places and it doesn't seem to be obvious, likewise for the uni-variate case....

Comment: This looks linear in $f$, unless I'm missing something. What does $f$ map from and to?

Comment: f maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$... does this cause a problem (also sorry about the non-linear claim... I'm not too experienced with ODEs...not my field :( )

Comment: Your $f$ doesn't cause any dimension problems. Both sides of this equation will end up being a vector.

Comment: I know, but I have no idea of how to approach this type of problem...

Comment: Do you happen to know what $n, A,$ and $B$ are? If so, could you please post them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the variables 
$$\eqalign{
C &= A^{-1}B \cr
\phi &= \log(f) \implies f = \exp(\phi)\cr 
}$$
Then
$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{f}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = Cx$$
Now we can write 
$$\eqalign{
\int d\phi &= \int (Cx)^Tdx \cr
}$$
If $C$ is symmetric, we can proceed to a solution
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \tfrac{1}{2}x^TCx + \phi_0 \cr
}$$
If $C$ is not symmetric, then I am stuck.

Comment: Coolio!  Thanks greg :)